# Isomorphims on homologies induced by cylindrical structure

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

This question is related to my previous question [Cylindrical structure and homology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110864/cylindrical-structure-and-homology).

Let $S$ be a oriented compact (topological) 2-manifold. We consider a cylinder $M=S\times I$ over $S$, here $I=[0, 1]$.

By pushing a loop in the bottom boundary $S \times 0$ to a loop in in the top boundary $S \times I$ using a cylindrical structure of $S\times I$, we have an isomorphism $f: H_1(S\times 0, \mathbb{Z}) \to H_1(S \times 1, \mathbb{Z})$.

Is $f$ identity isomorphism? 
(if we assume the identification of $S \times 0$ with $S\times 1$?)